# canvas not drawing in java android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I think the code is right, but I'm unable to find what's going wrong. Can anyone help please in figuring out what's incorrect ?

Thats the activity document:

```
package com.example.crazyeights;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CrazyEightsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView view = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_eights, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

thats what i want to display in the screen:

```
package com.example.crazyeights;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class MyView extends View{

    private Paint redPaint;
    private int circleX;
    private int circleY;
    private float radius;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        redPaint = new Paint();
        redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        circleX = 100;
        circleY = 100;
        radius = 30;
    }
    protected void OnDraw(Canvas canvas){
             canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uppercase OnDraw() method you specified will not be called that way. You actually need to override the onDraw() method when using a custom view, e.g:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(circleX, circleY, radius, redPaint);
}
```

I tested it and that draws a red circle. See documentation on Custom Drawing [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html), specifically the **Override onDraw()** section.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add, in your constructor redPaint.setStyle(...)
for example:

redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)
redpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);