# Android - Trouble displaying canvas in while loop

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm very new to Android and Java and I am facing a problem in trying to repetitively display a canvas in a while loop. The canvas does not seem to be displayed until the onCreate method ends and my while loop is in the onCreate method. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.clip_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rect);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bmp);
        Paint paint=new Paint();

        while (true) {

            //DISPLAY RED SQUARE

            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,paint);
            ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
            SystemClock.sleep(250);

            //DISPLAY BLUE SQUARE

            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
            canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,paint);
            ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
            SystemClock.sleep(250);

        }

    }

}
```

I've looked up other examples of how a canvas is regularly updated but the codes involve other complications (such as handling touch events) which I have to understand before getting used to canvases. Can anyone show me a simple code about how I can get this done?

Comment: If touch events seem complicated, then please learn them first. They are a trivial topic when compared to performing animation. Then you can understand the examples. Or look for simpler examples yourself (we are not your engine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your code like this

```
    private Handler handler;
    private BitmapDrawable bg1;
    private BitmapDrawable bg2;
    private LinearLayout ll;

    private Runnable setBgRunnable1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ll.setBackgroundDrawable(bg1);
            handler.postDelayed(setBgRunnable2, 250);
        }
    };

    private Runnable setBgRunnable2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ll.setBackgroundDrawable(bg2);
            handler.postDelayed(setBgRunnable1, 250);
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rect);
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        Paint paint=new Paint();

        //DISPLAY RED SQUARE

        Bitmap bmp1=Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bmp1);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,paint);
        bg1 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp1);

        //CREATE BLUE SQUARE

        Bitmap bmp2=Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas=new Canvas(bmp2);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
        canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,paint);
        bg2 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp2);

        // CREATE HANDLER
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(setBgRunnable1, 250);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare a view to draw on, then override the onDraw method for that view to access the canvas. This answer ([canvas not drawing in java android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556225/canvas-not-drawing-in-java-android?rq=1)) has an example.

Edit: Then you can leave your timing control and while loop in `onCreate` or in `onResume`. Declare a `paint` for each colour, and put something like this in `onDraw`:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
    if (wantToDrawRed) {
        canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,redPaint);
    }
    if (wantToDrawBlue) {
        canvas.drawRect(50,50,200,200,bluePaint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

There are several ways to do it.